# How do I interpret and resolve this webpack "ReferenceError: document is not defined" compilation error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, antd

The short version of my question is i'm getting the following "ReferenceError : document is not defined" error when trying to run my dev-server (yarn run dev-server) and i'm not sure how to interpret nor fix what the compilation problem is.

Seems like it's saying that MiniCssExtractPlugin is trying to extract ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.less and is unable to because a document is not defined. But i'm not even sure if that's what the error is trying to tell me nor what document? So i'm primarily looking for help in how to interpret the error message.

Secondarily i'd love any help resolving it.

[image]

I got myself into this mess when I decided I should update my `webpack.config.js` file to use MiniCSSExtractPlugin instead of ExtractTextWebpackPlugin because [that's what webpack recommends](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/extract-text-webpack-plugin/). Before, my app compiled and ran with proper styling fine. Here is the prior working `webpack.config.js`..

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env.test' });
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env.development' });
}

module.exports = (env) => {
  const isProduction = env === 'production';
  const CSSExtract = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css');

  return {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/app.js'],
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
      rules: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      }, {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: CSSExtract.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS
            }, {
              loader: 'less-loader', // compiles Less to CSS
              options: {
                modifyVars: {
                  'primary-color': '#1c88bf',
                  'link-color': '#1c88bf',
                  'border-radius-base': '2px',
                },
                javascriptEnabled: true,
              },
            }]
        })
      }, {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: CSSExtract.extract({
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: !isProduction,
              },
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: !isProduction,
              },
            },
          ],
        }),
      }, {
        test: /\.(svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: "[name].[ext]",
            outputPath: 'fonts/',
          },
        },
      }],
    },
    plugins: [
      CSSExtract,
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY),
        'process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN),
        'process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL),
        'process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID),
        'process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET),
        'process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID)
      })
    ],
    devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
      historyApiFallback: true,
      publicPath: '/dist/'
    }
  };
};
```

And here is my current (broken?) `webpack.config.js`.

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
  require("dotenv").config({ path: ".env.test" });
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  require("dotenv").config({ path: ".env.development" });
}

module.exports = (env) => {
  const isProduction = env === "production";

  return {
    entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./src/app.js"],
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "public", "dist"),
      filename: "bundle.js",
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
          test: /\.less$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            },
            "style-loader",
            "css-loader",
            {
              loader: "less-loader",
              options: {
                modifyVars: {
                  "primary-color": "#1c88bf",
                  "link-color": "#1c88bf",
                  "border-radius-base": "2px",
                },
                javascriptEnabled: true,
              },
            }
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.s?css$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            },
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                sourceMap: !isProduction,
              },
            },
            {
              loader: "sass-loader",
              options: {
                sourceMap: !isProduction,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
          use: {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[ext]",
              outputPath: "fonts/",
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY": JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY),
        "process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN": JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN),
        "process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL": JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL),
        "process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID": JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID),
        "process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET": JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET),
        "process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID": JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID),
      }),
    ],
    devtool: isProduction ? "source-map" : "inline-source-map",
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
      historyApiFallback: true,
      publicPath: "/dist/",
    },
  };
};
```

And related, here is my `.babelrc`. I've tried both `css` and `true` in the `style` parameter but neither results in anything different.

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    [
      "import",
      {
        "libraryName": "antd",
        "libraryDirectory": "es",
        "style": "true"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I notice if i remove line 35 ("style-loader",) It compiles but my application loses all of it's antd styling. Ultimately, I think(?) this whole problem revolves around adding antd styling to my application.

Originally, I essentially followed andt's customize theme documentation [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme) to get it to work.

My `app.js` file has an `import "antd/dist/antd.less";` statement in it.

Comment: when you go to this file mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js where document is mentioned ?

Comment: if you mean `./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js`, there is no `mini-css-extract-plugin` directory within the node_modules folder.

Comment: okey here it is looking for document so you can npm install jsdom as it will make window and document available

Comment: i'm confused. why jsdom? originally i installed mini-css-extract-plugin via yarn add -dev mini-css-extract-plugin as outlined on the MiniCssExtractPlugin page. So i'd imagine there is no mini-css-extract-plugin in my app's node_modules directory because it wasn't installed locally..?

Comment: based on webpack documentation when you run npm install --save-dev mini-css-extract-plugin you should get the mini-css-extract-plugin inside your node_modules

Comment: so on the premise that the folder doesn't exist being the problem, I did a yarn cache clear, deleted the node_modules folder, and did a yarn install. The folder is now there in my project's node_modules folder. But when I try my yarn run dev-server I still get the same error exactly as above. So that didn't appear to be the problem.

Comment: in other words, `./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js` does indeed exist in my app's folder.

Comment: ok next step is to look inside this loader.js if it containes the document variable

Comment: which variable? do you mean `indexStyleElement`? if so, loader.js does not